# Using PHP broadcast to detect Server IP address

Tags: php, sockets, ip, broadcastreceiver

I want to do something like this article:
[broadcast to detect Server IP address](http://blog.javamonday.com/2012/05/using-java-udp-broadcast-to-detect.html)

and transfer to PHP, does it possible?

The reason is I want to send broadcast socket to server, and the server will return message then I can determine the message is what I want or not to detect the true IP of the message sender.

The code is like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$address = "255.255.255.255";
$port = 10000;

/* Create a udp socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br/>";
} else {
    echo "socket successfully created.<br/>";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$port'..."."<br/>";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br/>";
} else {
    echo "successfully connected to $address."."<br/>";
}


$i="theMessage";
echo "Sending $i to server."."<br/>";
socket_write($socket, $i, strlen($i));

$input = socket_read($socket, 512);
echo "Response from server is: $input"."<br/>";
$ip="";
if($input=="I want")
       $ip=socket_send_from_the_IP;   // just psuedocode


echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Or is the direction of my question wrong?
I also think that I should use httprequest?

Any answer appreciated.

Comment: What is it you exactly want to accomplish? Is there a LAN situation and you want to know your server's local IP address? Or do you just want to know your server's public IP address? Or do you want to know the visitor's IP address?

Comment: like the link(java version), it is in LAN, and I want to know the server's local IP address, thank you.

Comment: I think you would be better off `exec()`uting something like ifconfig and get the **possible** binded IP's from there. There could be multiple IP's available. And then it's also the questions to which IP's your web server is listening.

Comment: Ow and by the way. Are you sure `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` doesn't contain just what you want? It would actually surprise me if that were to hold the public IP address over the local IP address. Assuming this script will be run via a webserver

Comment: The local address what I want will changed because of dhcp, so I use broadcast and send message then look what server response is the fix message that I need, and try to find which server send the message->the IP of the server is what I want.

Maybe I should do Linux script or other trick to do it?
Since the server is in Linux environment.
Thanks again!